# Error trapping when updating a hibernate data instance

Tags: hibernate, grails

Running grails 2.3.3 I have spent time fixing an error occurring during a hibernate data instance update.

I identified the problem only when checking that the underlying data tables had not been changed as the error trapping had not flagged any issue.

Here is the code:

```
        try{
        currSlot.properties = currSlotBindMap

        // currSlot.properties updated now save all upd transactions dB
        try{
            def saveRtn = currSlot.save(flush: true) 
        }
        catch (Exception eWrite)
        {
            returnValue = null
        }
    }
    catch (Exception eWrite)
    {
        returnValue = null
    }
```

Neither the properties setting or the flush save produced any errors - however the updates never appeared in the underlying datastore.

The only sign that there was any problem was that when the save failed the saveRtn set a null value whereas when the save was successful saveRtn contained the id of the instance that was saved:

> ```
>   saveRtn: homevu1.VidSlotData : 868
> ```

I could build some check based on this difference in the return value but I am surprised that no error occurred.

Would welcome any suggestions and ideas on how to trap these sort of data update problems?

Incidentally the problem was a result of data type clashing during the update.

-mike

Comment: No error occurs because exceptions can cost a lot of CPU cycles and somebody could potentially DDOS your website simply by providing invalid data. If you feel this is not a problem in your situation, you can enable exceptions as the given answer suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)` the `failOnError` will case an exception to be raised if saving fails.

You can read more about it in the Grails [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html).